# Is it possible to generalize and/or simplifiy these two "computed properties"

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, closures, block

I have a swift project where I'm using Notifications to pass data around.  When I post the notification I'm encoding `["data" : data ]` in the message

`data` is of the type `ParsedMessage` of which I have multiple subtypes that follow from it.

When I receive the notification I'm using the block style method to deal with the notification.  I did this because I wanted to try to avoid the issues with misspelling or forgetting add the `:` at the end of the selector method.  I'm starting to think I'll end up with clearer code if I use selectors but as I'm exploring some of the swift funkiness I wanted to try this route at least.

So in any case I have two blocks to handle data which subclasses `ParsedMessage`, that being `AHRSMessage` and `LocationMessage`

```
// Define a block to be called by the notification center
lazy var ahrsDataHandler : notificationBlock = { notification in

    if let d : Dictionary = notification?.userInfo,
        msg : AHRSMessage = d["data"] as? AHRSMessage
    {

        println (msg.roll)

        self.expectation1!.fulfill()
    } else {
        println("\(__FILE__)::\(__LINE__)Could not parse AHRS Data correctly")
    }

}

// Define a block to be called by the notification center
lazy var locationDataHandlerBlock : notificationBlock = { notification in

    if let d : Dictionary = notification?.userInfo,
        msg : LocationMessage = d["data"] as? LocationMessage
    {
        println("Latitude: \(msg.lat)")

        self.expectation1!.fulfill()
    } else {
        println("\(__FILE__)::\(__LINE__)Could not parse Location Data correctly")
    }

}
```

Eventually these two **computed properties** are passed into a call to:

`addObserverForName(...)` which takes a block.

Is there a way to use Generics and/or something i missed to simplify this code?

Calling `if let d : Dictionary = notification?.userInfo,
        msg : AHRSMessage = d["data"] as? AHRSMessage` seems kind of unweildly

I'm wondering if there is some function I can construct where I could pass in a closure and a type or something and it would "generate" a similar block here to what I've created.

`func generateNotificationBlock<LocationMessage>()` or something but I've just ended up confusing myself.

Thanks

Comment: I know it's not what you are ultimately looking for, but you can simplify slightly by doing `if let msg = notification.userInfo?["data"] as? AHRSMessage ` if you don't need the userInfo dictionary directly.

Answer (score -1):

So I went the other direction and made a class extension to Notifications which worked great!

```
/**
These class extensions make it easier to work with Notificationss
*/
extension NSNotification {


    /**
    If the notificaiton has a UserInfo field that is equal to ["data" : AHRSMessage ], this function
    wiill extract the Location message otherwise it will return nil

    :returns: userInfo["data"] extracted as a AHRSMessage
    */
     var asAHRSMessage : AHRSMessage? {
        get { return self.asParsedMessage() }
    }


    /**
    If the notificaiton has a UserInfo field that is equal to ["data" : LocationMessage ], this function
    wiill extract the Location message otherwise it will return nil

    :returns: userInfo["data"] extracted as a LocationMessage
    */
     var asLocationMessage : LocationMessage? {
        get {
            return self.asParsedMessage()
        }
    }

    /**
    If the notificaiton has a UserInfo field that is equal to ["data" : ParsedMessage ], this function
    wiill extract the Location message otherwise it will return nil

    :returns: userInfo["data"] extracted as a ParsedMessage
    */
    private func asParsedMessage<T>() -> T? {
        if let d : Dictionary = self.userInfo,
            msg : T = d["data"] as? T
        {
            return msg
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```